# How to make a dataloader with a directory of subfolders relevant to each class in Pytorch

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

I have a dataset that contains images of brain tumoursl. I want to make a CNN to classify these images.What I have seen is a directory of images which is separated in “train” , “test” folders.

However, in this case, the dataset directory structure is as follows.

```bash
dataset_dir
|_____tumor_type_1
|_____tumor_type_2
|_____tumor_type_3
|_____no_tumor
```

Now, I want to make 3 dataloaders. ( a train_dataloader,a validation_dataloader & a test_dataloader.)
Does anyone know how to do this in PyTorch without writing a custom script.

TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use torchvision's ImageFolder class ([docs here](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/generated/torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder.html)), but you should first split your data to train/test/val in separate directories beforehand in this format:

```
├── train
│   ├── class1
|      ├── image-1.jpg
│      ├── image-2.jpg
│   ├── class2
|      ├── image-1.jpg
│      ├── image-2.jpg
├── val
│   ├── class1
|      ├── image-1.jpg
│      ├── image-2.jpg
│   ├── class2
|      ├── image-1.jpg
│      ├── image-2.jpg
├── test
│   ├── ...
...
```

to split the images randomly:

```py
import os
import shutil
import random

test_split = 0.2
valid_split = 0.2

if not os.path.exists('./new_dataset_dir'):
    os.mkdir('./new_dataset_dir')

os.mkdir('./new_dataset_dir/test')
os.mkdir('./new_dataset_dir/train')
os.mkdir('./new_dataset_dir/valid')

classes = os.listdir('./dataset_dir')

for c in classes:
    images = os.listdir('./dataset_dir/' + c)
    random.shuffle(images) # optional

    num_images = len(images)
    num_test = int(test_split * num_images)
    num_valid = int(valid_split * num_images)
    num_train = num_images - num_test - num_valid

    os.mkdir('./new_dataset_dir/test/' + c)
    os.mkdir('./new_dataset_dir/train/' + c)
    os.mkdir('./new_dataset_dir/valid/' + c)

    for idx, image in enumerate(images):
        split = 'train' if idx < num_train else 'valid' if idx < num_train + num_valid else 'test'
        shutil.move(f'./dataset_dir/{c}/{image}', f'./new_dataset_dir/{split}/{c}/{image}')
    
    os.rmdir('./dataset_dir/' + c)
```

Then you can easily create the dataloaders using ImageFolder:

```py
from torchvision.datasets import ImageFolder
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

train_dataset = ImageFolder(root='./new_dataset_dir/train')
val_dataset = ImageFolder(root='./new_dataset_dir/valid')
test_dataset = ImageFolder(root='./new_dataset_dir/test')

train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, ...)
valid_loader = DataLoader(val_dataset, ...)
test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset, ...)
```